# Cloning and extending class in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, reflection, metaprogramming, metaclass

I'm trying to generate classes dynamically in Groovy. My approach is this:

```
class MetaClassTest {

    static class TestClass {

        String getName() {
            return "Jake"
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        def testClass = TestClass
        def metaMethod = testClass.metaClass.getMetaMethod('getName', [] as Class[])
        testClass.metaClass.getName = {
            metaMethod.invoke(delegate) + " and the Fatman"
        }
        assert testClass.newInstance().name == "Jake and the Fatman"
    }
}
```

This however changes the behavior of the original class which is what I don't want. So my question is:

How can I clone (and probably rename) an existing class dynamically so that I'd be able to create multiple derivates?

Comment: so maybe that should be a usual `extends` ? `class MyTestClass extends TestClass`...

Comment: or use @Delegate:  `class MyTextClass{ @Delegate TestClass delegate; }`

Comment: That's not dynamic code (if not evaluated at runtime via `GroovyClassLoader`, which is an option too but not very nice one).

Comment: maybe you should extend your question? because your code example is not really dynamic also... what exactly should be dynamic?

Comment: generate classes dynamically - the easiest way is to generate the real class code with `extends` or `@Delegate` and parse/load it into class loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most transparent (even though still dirty) solution so far has been already hinted here. I can create the child class skeleton using the `GroovyClassLoader.parse()` method and then enrich it via `metaClass`.

```
class TestClass {

    String getName() {
        return "Jake"
    }
}

def parentClass = TestClass
def groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(parentClass.classLoader)

def childClass1 = groovyClassLoader.parseClass("class ChildClass1 extends ${ parentClass.canonicalName } {}")
def oldGetName1 = childClass1.metaClass.getMetaMethod('getName', [] as Class[])
childClass1.metaClass.getName = {
    oldGetName1.invoke(delegate) + " and the Fatman"
}

def childClass2 = groovyClassLoader.parseClass("class ChildClass2 extends ${ parentClass.canonicalName } {}")
def oldGetName2 = childClass2.metaClass.getMetaMethod('getName', [] as Class[])
childClass2.metaClass.getName = {
    oldGetName2.invoke(delegate) + " the Dog"
}

assert childClass1.newInstance().name == "Jake and the Fatman"
assert childClass2.newInstance().name == "Jake the Dog"
```

My reason to create classes dynamically at runtime is that the application can be extended using Groovy DSL scripts written by people with hardly any programming skills in general.

Answer (score 1):

You may override class instance methods:

```
import groovy.transform.AutoClone

@AutoClone
class TestClass {
   String getName() {
      return "Jake"
   }
}

def tc1 = new TestClass()
def tc2 = tc1.clone()
tc1.metaClass.getName = {'Fatman'}
tc2.metaClass.getName = {'Joe'}
assert tc1.getName() == 'Fatman'
assert tc2.getName() == 'Joe'
assert new TestClass().getName() == 'Jake'
```

Comment: I know, but that's not quite what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following works, but it may be worth a try: Can you check if you can somehow deep-copy the TestClass and then modify the only the cloned class? The folllowing might come in handy:

Use [autoclone](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2016/05/groovy-goodness-make-class-cloneable.html)

And maybe the [groovy lang metaprogramming](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html) to look for more on metaprogramming.